# Undesirable text overlapping

Tags: qt, overlap

When I edit the `QTableView` the old text is not cleared and so the new text overlaps it. How can I avoid this behaviour?

[image: text overlapping]

The code:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QtSql>
#include <QtGui>
#include <QTableView>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QSqlDatabase db1 = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
    db1.setDatabaseName(":memory:");
    db1.open();
    QSqlQuery("CREATE TABLE test (a integer primary key, s text)");
    QSqlQuery("INSERT INTO test VALUES (1, 'aaa');");

    QSqlTableModel *model = new QSqlTableModel(0, db1);
    model->setTable("test");
    model->select();

    QTableView *view = new QTableView;
    view->setModel(model);
    view->show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: did you use any qss(Qt Style Sheet)?

Comment: @RuslanF. I have not used any custom QSS, don't know if there are any default ones.

Comment: I have simular issue with dynamic QLabel. When label text is updated new text was overlaped with old one. The problem was related to transparent background color. Try setting background color into you tableView. Example: tableView->setStyleSheet("QTableView::item { background-color: white; }");

Comment: @RuslanF. Thanks, that worked. When I set background color I can't select a cell, but after setting empty stylesheet (`view->setStyleSheet("QTableView::item {}");`) everything seems to be ok. By the way, this error appears even in Qt 5.5 and even in QtCreator (when changing build environment). Could you formulate your comment as an answer, so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have simular issue with dynamic QLabel.
When label text is updated new text was overlaped with old one. The problem was related to transparent background color.
As you find out the solution for you is to use such stylesheet `QTableView::item {}`
Complete Code:

```
view->setStyleSheet("QTableView::item {}");
```